# creating a Wi-Fi hotspot without losing my internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am create a Wi-Fi hotspot using my computer(Ubuntu 12.04) from a mobile broadband connection. When I do this, I want to be able to access the internet myself and also other computers that join my network should be able to access the internet. So I dont just want to have a WiFi network but also internet connection in both my and other computers who have joined my network. Is there any way to do this with a normal computer (Acer aspire 1)?

Thanks for any help ;)